# Analytic function SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle

For each matter the order of the table CUSTOMERS display the name of the customer (companyname), and the following three columns - the minimum, maximum and average 
value of orders this customer with the discount (data from tables ORDERS and ORDERDETAILS).
***Note: It is assumed that the request will contain only one word SELECT.***
The scheme of databases:
[image]

```
select distinct c.companyname, 
sum(od.unitprice*od.quantity*(1-od.discount)) over (partition by o.orderid) as "SUM"
from customers c, orders o, orderdetails od where c.customerid=o.customerid 
and o.orderid=od.orderid
```

This query displays the total value of orders. As additionally find the minimum, maximum and average value of orders?

```
select c.companyname, 
min(od.unitprice*od.quantity*(1-od.discount)) over (partition by o.customerid) as "MIN",
max(od.unitprice*od.quantity*(1-od.discount)) over (partition by o.customerid) as "MAX",
avg(od.unitprice*od.quantity*(1-od.discount)) over (partition by o.customerid) as "AVG"
from customers c, orders o, orderdetails od 
where c.customerid=o.customerid and o.orderid=od.orderid
```

This query finds the minimum, maximum and average cost is not the whole order, but only sub-orders (as in one order may be several lots).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want `group by`, but twice.  Once at the `orders` level and once at the `customer` level:

```
select companyname, min(mino), max(maxo), sum(sumo)
from (select c.companyname, o.orderid,
             min(od.unitprice*od.quantity*(1-od.discount)) as mino
             max(od.unitprice*od.quantity*(1-od.discount)) as maxo
             sum(od.unitprice*od.quantity*(1-od.discount)) as sumo
      from customers c join
           orders o
           on c.customerid = o.customerid join
           orderdetails od 
           on o.orderid = od.orderid
      group by c.companyname, o.orderid
     ) co
group by companyname;
```

Note that I also introduced explicit `join` syntax.  If you are learning SQL, you should learn the right way to express joins, using the `join` keyword and the `on` clause.

EDIT:

One `select` is a ridiculous limitation.  Presuming this is for a course, it is even worse to impose such a restriction where modern join syntax is not a requirement.

But, I think it is possible.  Stupid query, but still possible.

```
      select distinct c.companyname,
             min(min(od.unitprice*od.quantity*(1-od.discount))) over (partition by companyname) as mino,
             max(max(od.unitprice*od.quantity*(1-od.discount))) over (partition by companyname) as maxo
             sum(sum(od.unitprice*od.quantity*(1-od.discount))) over (partition by companyname) as sumo
      from customers c join
           orders o
           on c.customerid = o.customerid join
           orderdetails od 
           on o.orderid = od.orderid
      group by c.companyname, o.orderid
```

I would never write a query like this.  The double nested aggregation is both clearer and probably has better performance.  But it is interesting (in a perverse way) that this could be done.

Comment: Note: It is assumed that the request will contain only one word SELECT.